# Como fazer um array push num objeto dentro de outro objeto

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Tenho um array de objetos e não estou conseguindo dar um push em determinado objeto, exemplo quero dar um push no titulo2 id mas nada do que fiz deu certo, segue a estrutura do array caso alguém saiba como fazer agradeço

```
 Objt = 
  [{ titulo1:
    [
      {
        id: id
      }
    ],      
     titulo2:
    [
      {
        id: id
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: Vc quer adicionar um novo item junto ao `id`? `id: id, outracoisa: valor`

Comment: isso quando eu der um push adicionar outro id no objeto, ex: titulo1: [{id:1}, {id:2}, ...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `Objt` possui apenas 1 índice `[0]` com 2 objetos. Você pode fazer um `push` no `titulo2` desta forma:

```
Objt[0].titulo2.push({id2: 'valor'});
```

Exemplo:

```js
Objt = 
  [{ titulo1:
    [
      {
        id: "id"
      }
    ],      
     titulo2:
    [
      {
        id: "id"
      }
    ]
  }]


Objt[0].titulo2.push({id2: 'valor'});
console.log(Objt[0].titulo2);
```

Comment: deu certo! estava tentando faz meio dia fazer isso, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

complementado, acho que sua intenção era fazer isso:

```
let Objt = 
  { titulo1:
    [
      {
        id: 1
      }
    ],      
    titulo2:
    [
      {
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
  Objt.titulo2.push ({id:2})
}
```

Comment: Note que na pergunta `Objt` é um array de objetos e na sua resposta `Objt` é um objeto com várias propriedades.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 
 let objeto = [{titulo1: [ { id: 'id'} ], titulo2: [{ id: 'id' }]}];
 
 //Adicionar key ao objeto existente
 objeto[0].titulo2[0].key1 = 'teste';
 //Faz o push de um novo objeto
 objeto[0].titulo2.push({id1: 'id1'});
```